# How to create relative entry in mongoldb using Django?

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I have following Person document model.

```
from djongo import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField


class Person(models.Model):
    
    id = models.ObjectIdField()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)


    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

And the following Comment model

```
class Comment:
        id = models.OneToOneField(
            Person,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            primary_key=True,
        )
        comments = ArrayField(models.CharField())
    
        objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

When I create a document in Person object, I want mongo automatically create a document in Comment model with the same id but empty comments. I thought declaring OneToOneField filed will do it, but it didn't. What should I do?

Comment: No, a `OneToOneField` might be e bit misleading. It means that each `Comment` has a *unique* `ForeignKey`, so that means that all models refer to a *different* `Person`, and thus a `Person` maps to at most *one* `Comment`. However, I do not see why you here use a separate model, why not move the `comments` to the `Person`?

Comment: Thank you for answer! Because firstly I want to create person. And allows user to comment person. So I don't want to update the the whole person document - just update comment filed by id